# click dynamically inflated views using robotium

Tags: android, robotium

In my application, I have inflated a view multiple times dynamically as the data comes from the server. For Example, I am inflating a `linearLayout` multiple times. Now I am trying to test the click on these dynamic views with robotium. The problem is that the layouts that are added dynamically have same id and these are added multiple times. How can I click each of the dynamically inflated linearlayouts.

Comment: Have you check if that layouts present in `solo.getViews()`. You can iterate through and check if it is required id.

Comment: Robotium is able to recognize views by id, index, text, so you can use indexes for layouts. Btw does it make sense to click on linear layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a static function that does what you want (i think, i do not have the android sdk or anything on my current machine so cannot test). I would not use it as a static function myself, I would put it somewhere that makes sense, but you can do with it what you want!

```
public static List<View> getViewsById(Solo solo, int id) {
    List<View> allViews = getViews();
    List<View> matchedViews = new ArrayList<View>();
    for(View view : allViews){
        if(view!=null && view.getId() == id){
            matchedViews.add(view);
        }
    }
    return matchedViews;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `solo.getView(view.class,index).performClick();` to get the view in the specific index and click on it.

Comment: I thought about this method but it will give you all classes, without filtering by id. As far as i understand the question this won't be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by several ways. One simple solution is when you inflate a view, apply a click listener at that time. Like if you are using some loop, in each iteration, add click listener there in loop.